# The StateObject in SwiftUI doesn't preserve states after the view disappeared

Tags: swiftui

I would like `StateObject` preserve state even after its view disappeared. But I failed. Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var b: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $b, label: {Text("Show Button")})
            if b {A()} else {Text("hi")}
        }
    }
}
struct A: View {
    @StateObject var o: Obj = Obj()
    var body: some View {
        Button {o.i += 1} label: {Text("i == \(o.i.description)")}
    }
}
class Obj: ObservableObject {
    @Published var i: Int = 1
}
```

After the Toggle switched, the state `o.i` was reseted to 1. How can I preserve the state?

Comment: Have you tried moving up the `StateObject` to your ContentView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var b: Bool = false
    @StateObject var o: Obj = Obj()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $b, label: {Text("Show Button")})
            if b {A(o: o)} else {Text("hi")}
        }
    }
}

struct A: View {
    @ObservedObject var o: Obj
    var body: some View {
        Button {o.i += 1} label: {Text("i == \(o.i.description)")}
    }
}
```